# $X$ involved in the Poincare-Hopf theorem is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

As an independent project and after reading the first three chapters in the book $\textit{Differential Topology}$ by Victor Guillemin and Alan Pollack, I am trying to prove the Poincare-Hopf Theorem. So, after analyzing some of the conditions given in the theorem and the definition of manifold given in the book I ran into a question. The theorem says:

If $F$ is a smooth vector field on the compact, oriented $k$-dimensional manifold $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with only finitely many zeroes, then the global sum of the indices of $F$ equals the Euler characteristic of $X$.

So, is $X$ a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Is this true for the theorem? Along the book I think the author did not mention anything about all what is implied for a general manifold (second countable, and all that).

Maybe this is a basic question in differential topology but I would really appreciate your help here, since this could drastically change my approach.

Thanks for all!!

Comment: That is not necessary. I did not read the book, so dont know exactly why they made this assumption. But the whitney embedding theorem says that every compact smooth manifold embeds smoothly into some $\mathbb R$, so it is not a restriction.

Comment: The entire book of Guillemin and Pollack works *only* with submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$. Once you know how to define abstract differentiable manifolds, the proof of Poincaré-Hopf will still work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Then, I can continue with my work. :)